# Updating a table column from the lowest value of another table column

Tags: php, mysql

Table1:

```
ID |  SKU | Images
------------------
1  | 1502 | Link1
2  | 1852 | Link2
3  | 1745 | Link3
```

Table2:

```
ID | Product | MainLink
------------------------
1  | 1501    | Link1
2  | 1502    | Link1
3  | 1852    | Link2
3  | 1745    | Link3
```

I am trying to update SKU from Table1 with the lowest value of each MainLink in Table2

Result would be:

Table1:

```
ID |  SKU | Images
------------------
1  | 1501 | Link1
2  | 1852 | Link2
3  | 1745 | Link3
```

This is the query I have so far but id does not get me the lowest value:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Images = t2.MainLink SET t1.SKU = t2.Product
```

Comment: See SQL's [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(Product) Product, MainLink 
    FROM Table2 GROUP BY Table2.MainLink
) t2 ON t1.Images = t2.MainLink SET t1.SKU = t2.Product
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting #1054 - Unknown column 't2.MainLink' in 'on clause'

Comment: I fixed it, now I am getting this error:  #1062 - Duplicate entry '16998' for key 'SKU'

Comment: Yes but this can have nothing to do with this answer maybe you have the same Table2.Product whit is setted up for two different links. And then when you are updating Table1 you have unique constraint on SKU.

Try this and watch if you multiple records 

SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Product = 16998